# Web server does not respond in spite of the fact all K8S indicators are OK

Tags: kubernetes

I have K8S 1.26 cluster on 3 ubuntu VMs, one control plaine and 2 nodes , I apply a deployment as well as a service and forward port 80 to port 80. Issuing the following commands show that everything is OK

[image]

[image]

However, when I browse to localhost:80, I get nothing always either connection refused or timedout.

Here is the deployment.yml and the service.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stable-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aspnetcore
      track: stable
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aspnetcore
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stable-app
        image: stable-app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
        resources: {}

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: stable-service
  labels:
    app: aspnetcore
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: aspnetcore
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

I checked port 80 it is not used by any other apps and it is free, I tried port 8080 instead of 80, it did not help. So what is missing for this to make the web server respond?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Browse to the correct interface.

Comment: And please, don't post text that you could just copy&paste as screenshots. You are just making it harder for people to extract information.

Comment: Do you have a `LoadBalancer` configured in your cluster?

Comment: Thanks, what is meant by "Browse to the correct interface"? do you mean port? Should I install LoadBalancer explicitly, if yes how ? I thought maybe mistakenly that it is existing with K8S setup.